# This vector definition with index in subscript is incorrect

Tags: variable-definitions

I am trying to define a vector of values. Here is an example

```
n = 8;

Table[Subscript[ω, i], {i, 1, n - 1}] = 
 Table[Sqrt[2], {i, 1, n - 1}]
```

Yet this leaves me with an error *"Tag Table in Table[Subscript[[Omega], i],{i,1,n-1}] is Protected. "*

I honestly can't find what is wrong here and what to do.

Comment: Do you may be mean this: `vec = Table[Subscript[\[Omega], i] = Sqrt[2], {i, 1, 7}];`. Then evaluation of `vec` returns `{Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2]}`, while evaluation of, say, `Subscript[\[Omega], 1]` returns `Sqrt[2]`.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Yes this is exactly what I wanted. I can see my syntax was wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest

```
With[{n = 8},
  Do[Subscript[ω, i] = Sqrt[2], {i, n - 1}]]
DownValues @ Subscript
```

[image: result]